# Reverse Linked list Java memory

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I was doing this leetcode problem and I don't understand why this solution doesn't work. It seems to only be returning the head element. Thanks

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {       
        ListNode curr = null;
        ListNode lst = null;
        while (head != null)
        {
            curr = head;
            curr.next = lst;
            lst = curr;
            head = head.next;
        }

        return curr;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about reference and object in java little bit. Java always passes copy of reference. So when you do,

```
 curr = head;
```

curr and head point to same object. And when you do,

```
 curr.next = lst;
```

Both curr.next as well as head.next both starts pointing to null (as lst in null).
And you loop breaks next time.

Try this solution it will work.

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {       
        ListNode nxt = null;
        ListNode lst = null;
        while (head != null)
        {
            nxt = head.next;
            head.next = lst;
            lst = head;
            head = nxt;
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have done a good job explaining the problem.  To fix the problem, I think all you need in your loop is this:

```
lst = curr;
curr = head;
head = head.next;
curr.next = lst;
```

This will traverse the list and reverse the pointers.

Is that what you're looking for?

So the full code:

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {       
        ListNode curr = null;
        ListNode lst = null;
        while (head != null)
        {
            lst = curr;
            curr = head;
            head = head.next;
            curr.next = lst;
        }
        return curr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when you set `curr = head;`, you are setting `curr` as a reference to `head`. So when you set `head = head.next` it is setting `head` to null and ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
curr = head;
```

The above line stores reference of `head` object in `curr` variable.

```
curr.next = lst;
```

Now this makes `head.next` = `null` as the `lst` is initially `null` and `curr` is holding the reference of `head` object.

```
lst = curr;
```

You are making variable `lst` to reference `curr` which is actually `head`.

```
head = head.next;
```

Now as explained earlier `head.next` is `null` so the loop terminates. `curr` is pointing to `head`. You have modified the original list which is containing just head of the original list.