# Recursion - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError during linked-list reversal

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Im writing a code to reverse a linkedlist using a recursion. Im getting this error, couldn't understand why? Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; next = null; }
 * }
 */

public class Solution{
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode a){
        if(a==null || a.next==null)return a;       
        ListNode ans=null;
        ans = reverse(a,ans);
        return ans;
    }
    private ListNode reverse(ListNode aa, ListNode ans){
        if(aa.next==null){
            ans = aa;
            return ans;
        }
        ans = reverse(aa.next, ans);
        ListNode temp = aa.next;
        temp.next=aa;
        aa.next=null;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance you have a cycle in your list?

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: Now is a good time to spend some time learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: Im getting this error during submission. I cant know for what input it is failing. For normal sized linked-list its working fine. @njzk2 I dont think list contains cycles as my iterative code worked fine.

Comment: This is not a task that should be done with recursion, because with enough input data, any recursive algorithm will have a stack overflow, and there are ways to do this without recursion that are much more efficient.  See [my answer to this question about an identical task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077829/reverse-linked-list-java-memory)

Comment: Thanks @RaceYouAnytime. Yeah I already solved this problem using iterative approach. I was just trying recursive one.

Comment: for list of more than 65000 elements, or for lists with cycles, you'll get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code by creating snippet:

```
public class Solution {

    public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode a){
        if(a==null || a.next==null)return a;
        ListNode ans=null;
        ans = reverse(a,ans);
        return ans;
    }

    private static ListNode reverse(ListNode aa, ListNode ans){
        if(aa.next==null){
            ans = aa;
            return ans;
        }
        ans = reverse(aa.next, ans);
        ListNode temp = aa.next;
        temp.next=aa;
        aa.next=null;
        return ans;
    }

    public static class ListNode {
        public int data;       // data stored in this node
        public ListNode next;  // link to next node in the list

        // post: constructs a node with data 0 and null link
        public ListNode() {
            this(0, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and null link
        public ListNode(int data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

        // post: constructs a node with given data and given link
        public ListNode(int data, ListNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode last = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode middle = new ListNode(2, last);
        ListNode first = new ListNode(1, middle);

        ListNode listNode = reverseList(first);

        System.out.println(listNode.data);
        System.out.println(listNode.next.data);
        System.out.println(listNode.next.next.data);

    }

}
```

By running this simple test I assume code is working correctly. You have to visualize how linked list is working, because most likely you have cycle in your linked list, and that is why you are getting an error.